# Page objects not being run in webdriverio setup

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io, pageobjects

I've created a test script in **webdriverio** (version 6.14.13) and mocha, which uses the *page object* functionality.

This is because some of my test script is used in the vast majority of my other scripts, and I thought the best way to overcome this repetition of code would be to use *page objects*.

So, this is my *page object* script, called `removeNotifications.js` which I've added into my `pages` folder;

```
class clearNotifications {
    get closeTheCmp() {
        const cmpDismissal = $('~ACCEPT AND CLOSE');
        if (cmpDismissal.isExisting()) {
                cmpDismissal.click();
                cmpDismissal.waitForExist({ reverse: true });
        }
    }
    get allowNotifications() {
        const notificationsDismissal = $('~Allow');
        if (notificationsDismissal.isExisting()) {
                notificationsDismissal.click();
                notificationsDismissal.waitForExist({ reverse: true });
        }
    }
    get skipToContent() {
        const skipButton = $('~SKIP');
        skipButton.waitForExist({timeout: 50000});
        skipButton.isExisting();
        skipButton.click();
    }
}
export default new clearNotifications();
```

and now, in my test script, I have the following code;

```
var clearNotifications = require ('../pages/removeNotifications.js');

describe('testing the app cmp.....', () => {
    it('Close CMP, Notifications and Skip to content...', async () => {
        await clearNotifications.closeTheCmp();
        await clearNotifications.allowNotifications();
        await clearNotifications.skipToContent();
    });
```

However, the test is failing as it doesn't appear to be performing any of the `removeNotifications.js` functions?

I am doing something wrong within my `removeNotifications.js` script, and not defining it correctly?

Or is the problem with my test script not 'calling' the `removeNotifications.js` correctly and thus running the test without performing the functions detailed in the `removeNotifications.js` script?

Any help would greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You done mistake in your get methods in get we return the selectors and then use them in our functions i will put example in Answer below

Answer (score 0):

class clearNotifications {

```
   get closeTheCmpGetter() {
        return $('~ACCEPT AND CLOSE');   
    }
    async closeTheCmp(){

    const cmpDismissal = await this.closeTheCmpGetter;

    if (await cmpDismissal.isExisting()) {
          await cmpDismissal.click();

          await cmpDismissal.waitForExist({ reverse: true });

        }
    }
```

}
//export default new clearNotifications();

module.exports = new clearNotifications();

Comment: Many thanks for your help @Nadir. I've now changed my _clearNotifications_ script accordingly, and I now reference this in my test script as such; 

`import clearNotifications from '../pages/closeCmp.page.js';

describe('Test Car App homepage elements load', () => {
 it('close cmp', async () => {
  await clearNotifications.closeTheCmpGetter();
 });`

However, this results in the following error;

`[0-0] 2022-10-17T12:59:39.403Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialised.`

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Also, the error includes 
`[0-0] import clearNotifications from '../pages/closeCmp.page.js';
[0-0] ^^^^^^
[0-0] 
[0-0] SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
`

Comment: did you add your test in spec array in wdio.config file ?

Comment: try the new way to export file
module.exports = new clearNotifications();
and for import use : 
const variableName=require('../pages/closeCmp.page.js');
and your file in spec in wdio.config

Comment: Hi @Nadir. So I've changed my code to be as your suggestion, and referenced it in my test script with `const clearNotifications = require('./pangeaTests/ios/test-scripts/commands/closeCmp.js');`. 

But I now get the warning `[0-0] 2022-10-19T09:24:00.862Z WARN @wdio/mocha-framework: Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialised.`

and the error; `ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialised.`

Comment: And the error `Error:  Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on browser object that is not fully initialised.`

Comment: seems you made mistakes in giving Paths somewhere ... check your path in spec array in wdio.config.js